# Rate of rationals in a closed set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, rational-numbers

Let $B$ a closed subset of $[0,1]$ of positive measure. 
I'm interested in the asymptotic density of the rationals in $B$.

More specifically, my question is

> Let $a_n$ be 
>   $$ a_n = \frac{|\{k\in \mathbb N : \frac{k}{n}\in B\}|}{n}. $$
>   Is it true that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \mu(B)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure?

I get a feeling that  it's true, but  I'm afraid that there's some weird set not satisfying it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a closed subset $B \subset [0,1]$ of positive Lebesgue measure $\mu(B)$ consisting entirely of irrational numbers. For example, enumerate $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] = \{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ and define 
$$B = [0,1] - \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \,\,(x_i - \frac{1}{10^i},x_i + \frac{1}{10^i})
$$
and so $\mu(B) \ge 1 - \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2}{10^i} = \frac{7}{9}$.

But $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 \ne \mu(B)$.

Comment: Darn! I just saw this question a few minutes ago, started writing an answer, and then someone came by my cubical for something (I'm at work), and by the time they left your answer had appeared.

Comment: I was thinking about enlarged Cantor.. The answer instead was the complementary of the enlarged rationals..
IThe counterexamples are always one of them anyway..

Comment: In case you're (Exodd) interested, a common problem in real analysis texts is to construct a Cantor set that contains no rational numbers. I've also occasionally seen this problem on (U.S.) Ph.D. qualifying exams. Note that the standard proof (which Mosher gave) shows you can do this for any countable set, for example the algebraic numbers.